# "Freue mich auf" + Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Ich glaube, dass man "Ich freue mich auf dich" sagt. Wie kommt es, dass es im Akkusativ steht und nicht im Dativ, z. B. "Ich freue mich auf dir"?

Comment: Der Akkusativ ist mit einer *Richtungs*semantik assoziiert im Gegensatz zur *Orts*semantik: man geht *in den Zoo*, aber vergnügt sich *im Zoo*. Und sich auf jemanden zu freuen hat den Charakter einer geistigen Ausrichtung auf zukünftige Gemeinschaft und nicht einer bereits eingetretenen Gemeinschaft.

Comment: In Berlin sagen sie wahrscheinlich: _Ich freue mich auf dir_. Dort werden Dativ und Akkusativ nicht so genau unterschieden.

Comment: Sind Kombinationen (Verb, Präposition, Fall) wirklich rechtzufertigen? Warum *glauben an* **A** aber *zweifeln* **D** ?

Comment: Als allgemeine Regel für die Präposition "auf", kannst du dir merken, dass sie von einem Dativ gefolgt wird, wenn räumlich, statisch. In allen anderen Fällen ist es meist der Akkusativ. Siehe auch [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html?MenuId=Word733#Anchor-auf-27347)

Comment: Da _freuen_ auch rein reflexiv verwendet werden kann und es stimmt, was @Em1 schreibt, ist auch _Ich freue mich auf dir_ syntaktisch korrekt. Es bedeutet allerdings etwas anderes: ‘Ich freue mich und befinde mich dabei auf dir.’

Comment: Das erinnert mich übrigens an einen (imho schlechten) Witz aus einer Comedy-Show. Dort sah man zwei Freundinnen am Pool liegen und die eine meinte: "Der Typ steht auf mir." Und die andere sagte: "Du meinst, er steht auf dich." Und die erste wieder: "Nein, nein. Er steht auf mir." Dann zoomte die Kamera aus und ein Typ stand auf ihrem Rücken.

Comment: @crissov und  Em1, ist schon gut, Jungs, schaltet mal  Euren PC aus und eventuell findet Ihr dann eine, auf der..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ich freue mich auf dich" ist richtig. Sich auf etwas freuen ist ein 'transitives Verb' und steht im Deutschen mit dem Akkusativobjekt, also einem direkten Objekt. Ein Dativobjekt wäre im Gegenzug ein indirektes Objekt, welches für den Satz nicht unbedingt nötig wäre (wie z. B. "Ich schreibe [dir] einen Brief."). Transitive Verben benötigen zwei Argumente, d. h. (in einem aktivischen Satz) Subjekt und Objekt.

Siehe auch die Wiki-Artikel zu [Objekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objekt_%28Grammatik%29) und [Transitivität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A4t_%28Grammatik%29).

Comment: Willkommen. Eine Frage: Ist aber nicht das vom transitiven Verb benötigtes Akkusativobjekt eben *mich*?

Comment: Ich denke, dass es in diesem Fall offenbar drei Argumente benötigt werden. Denn es heißt ja _sich_ auf _etwas_ freuen.

Comment: *sich* bedeutet hier Reflexivität, was mit Transivität recht wenig gemeinsam hat.

Comment: Es ist nicht transitiv, zumindest nicht wegen des *auf jemanden.* Oder wie bildest du das Passiv: Auf du wirst gefreut?